# How to insert files according to the positions and following the amount defined from another list(in an excel sheet)?

Tags: python, openpyxl

Ok, so the problemn is ive 2 lists, 1 including the namepath of each image that gonna be inserted in the worksheet, the other one shows the amount of files per subfolder, **ive to insert them according to the amount of images per subfolder**. These are the list output:

```
filepersubdir = [4, 2, 2]#amount of jpgs files per subfolder
imageslist = ['image1.jpg','image2.jpg','image3.jpg','image4.jpg','image5.jpg','image6.jpg','image7.jpg','image8.jpg']#total will vary
```

As showed above theres a total of 8 images inside the subfolder split in 4 into the subfolder1, 2 into subfolder2 and 2 on subfolder3, with that said, thats how i need to insert the files into the sheet:

[image]

The pattern is , if the image is inside the same subfolder its going to skip 4 rows than insert, if  its from the next subfolder its going to skip 8 rows than insert, so heres what ive tried:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.drawing.image import Image
from PIL import Image as pilimage

workbook = Workbook()

#put the images into the positions. But it needs to work accordingly to the amount of files into each subfolder
for index, image in enumerate(imageslist):
    VALUE = 'B'
    #resize each image before inserting
    oldsize = pilimage.open(image)
    newsize = oldsize.resize((150,150))
    newsize.save(image)
    #conditions to insert into the sheet according to the required position pattern, but its not considering the amount of files per subfolder
    if index == 1:
        VALUE = 'C'
    if index <=1:
        index = 2
    elif index%4 == 2:
        index = aux+4
    elif index%4 == 0:
        index = aux+8
    else:
        index=aux
        VALUE = 'C'
    aux=index
    worksheet.add_image(Image(image), anchor=VALUE+str(int(index)))
workbook.save('Images.xlsx')
```

The code Works, but it doesnt take into consideration the filepersubdir list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should make your life easier by making your image list a list of tuples with left and right image. This will allow you to easier loop and not have so many cases to cover. If you can't change the list, convert it (done here for explicitly) or directly iterate over the result of the zip function (recommended):

```
filepersubdir = [4, 2, 2]#amount of jpgs files per subfolder
o_imageslist = ['image1.jpg','image2.jpg','image3.jpg','image4.jpg','image5.jpg','image6.jpg','image7.jpg','image8.jpg']
# Convert to list of tuples with left/right image
imagelist = list(zip(o_imageslist[::2],o_imageslist[1::2]))
```

After that, when looping over the image list, just keep track of your current subdir (or the index of the filepersubdir list), your row and how many images from that subdir you have processed.

```
row = 2 # startrow
subdiridx = 0 # startindex for filepersubdir
imgsubdircount = 0 # files processed from current subdir
for leftimg, rightimg in imagelist:
    print("put {} to B{}".format(leftimg, row))
    print("put {} to C{}".format(rightimg, row))
    imgsubdircount += 2
    if imgsubdircount >= filepersubdir[subdiridx]:
        # proceed to next subdir
        row += 8
        subdiridx += 1
        imgsubdircount = 0
    else:
        # stay in current subdir
        row += 4
```